# Shaken harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I cannot find in literature an exact expression of the probability of transition of the eigenvectors of the quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian when it is "shaken" in this way:
\begin{equation} H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x-x(t))^2\end{equation}
I found only first order approximations with a "forcing" term $m\omega^2 x(t)x=F(t)x$, which is well known in literature, but this is not enough for me, since I am looking for high (>0.5) transition probabilities, not reachable with the first order approximation.

Comment: You are right :) I apologize, English is not my mother language. Speaking about physics, do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. I assume $x(t)$ is the position of the equilibrium point of the oscillator, which is being shaken. Intuitively I would assume that this could be modeled as a forced harmonic oscillator. Why do you think the "forcing" is a first-order approximation? Also, shouldn't the forcing term be some $F(t) x$ instead of $x(t) x$? Actually, how did you get this hamiltonian? Did you just replace $x$ with $x - x(t)$?

Comment: Exactly, we have a time-driven translation. In the question I meant that at the first order, you can write $m \frac{1}{2}\omega^2 (x-x(t))^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2+m\omega^2 x(t)x + o(x(t)^2)$, but I need an exact solution of the probability of transition, thus the approximation is not useful to me. I edit the question for more clarity, since I was actually a bit sloppy.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. What assumptions are you imposing on $x(t)$? Is it monochromatic? With a pulse? With arbitrary time dependence? Is it strong, or can it be considered weak? How does it compare to the ground state width? Is the system initially in the ground state?

Comment: Let me pose the question in this way: knowing the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator with $x(t)=0$, I would like to find an $x(t)$ which maximizes the probability of transition from $|0\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$. $x(t)$ is not necessarily weak.

Comment: There is also the method of strong perturbation theory. Are you okay with assuming that? Also, if all else fails, are you able to solve Schrodinger's equation?

Comment: That's the point! I am not able to solve Schrödinger equation in this scenario, but I am not very skilled in solving differential equations yet, thus I thought that maybe in literature there is something which can help me. I am starting thinking that this problem has no analytical solution

Comment: Sorry it seems you missed the point of my (apparently bad) comment.  Maybe I watched too many James Bond movies when I was young.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look for a solution to the nonstationary Schrodinger equation in this problem in the following form:
$$
|\Psi,t\rangle = \hat{U}(t)|\Psi,t\rangle_0\quad\mbox{where}\quad \hat{U}(t) = e^{-\frac{i}\hbar S(t)} e^{-\frac{i}\hbar\hat{p}x_1(t)} e^{\frac{i}\hbar\hat{x}p_1(t)}
$$
It is possible to choose functions $x_1(t)$, $p_1(t)$ and $S(t)$ in such a way that $|\Psi,t\rangle_0$ would be a solution to the Schrodinger equation for the unperturbed oscillator:
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi,t\rangle_0 = \hat{H}_0|\Psi,t\rangle_0\quad \mbox{where}\quad \hat{H}_0 = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{m\omega^2}2 \hat{x}^2.
$$
We just need to satisfy the following equality
$$
i\hbar \hat{U}^{-1}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{U}(t) = \hat{U}^{-1}(t)\hat{H}(t)\hat{U}(t) - \hat{H}_0.
$$
The operator $\hat{U}(t)$ properties are
$$
\hat{U}^{-1}(t)\hat{x}\hat{U}(t) = \hat{x} + x_1(t),\quad \hat{U}^{-1}(t)\hat{p}\hat{U}(t) = \hat{p} + p_1(t),
$$
$$
\hat{U}^{-1}(t)i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{U}(t) = \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}(t) + \dot{x}_1(t)p_1(t) + \dot{x}_1(t)\hat{p} - \dot{p}_1(t)\hat{x}
$$
Hence, functions $x_1(t)$, $p_1(t)$ and $S(t)$ should be solution to the following system of equations
$$
\dot{x}_1(t) = \frac{p_1(t)}m,\quad \dot{p}_1(t) = - m\omega^2(x_1(t)-x(t)),
$$
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}(t) = -p_1(t)\dot{x}_1(t) + \frac{p_1^2(t)}{2m} + \frac{m\omega^2}2(x_1(t)-x(t))^2.
$$
I think the last problem has a well-known solution. Now it is up to you to find this solution and to express the transition probability.